# System.Windows.Forms.Keys - Lower or Uppercase?

Tags: c#, winforms, case

I have been searching around for an answer to this but I can't seem to find anything. Does anyone know if you can determine the letter casing in `Keys`?

For example:

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.A.ToString() == "A")
{
    // Upper or Lower?
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no casing, it represents a physical key on your keyboard.  Do you see an 'a' and an 'A' on your keyboard?

You can check and see if a Shift key is depressed.

Comment: You should not check the shift key. There is simply no direct mapping between keys and characters.

Comment: I didn't say check THE shift key, I said check A shift key.  There is more than one and there is also the caplocks key to deal with.

Comment: My point is that the logic to determine what character corresponds to a keypress is complicated. You would have to consider stuff like dead-keys, sticky-keys and probably more I didn't even think of. Don't try to duplicate the functionality of keyboard layouts.

Comment: I agree with you.  However, we don't know what the requirements of the task are.  Sometimes the requirements override best practices.

Comment: Thanks guys, CodeInChaos your answer is very interesting and I wasn't aware of the WM_CHAR event, but Steve your answer pretty much answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Windows.Forms.Keys.A` represents the physical key <kbd>A</kbd> on your keyboard. It does not have a case. Thus, your question does not make sense.

If you want to check whether the user holds the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on the keybord, there's also `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple mapping between keys and characters. Keyboard layouts can work differently. One example are dead keys. And once you get to IMEs it gets even more complicated. Do not try to duplicate a keyboard layout manually in your application.

If you want to get what character a user entered, handle `WM_CHAR`, not `WM_KEY_DOWN/UP`. It's exposed as `Control.KeyPress` event in winforms.